Importing tricky data into SAS dataset
I have an excel file where the data is as below



Firstname
Lastname




Order#: AMS1



Document# Doc1



John
Fury


James
Berry



I want to export this kind of excel file in SAS dataset and transform data as



Order
Document
Firstname
Lastname




AMS1
Doc1
John
Fury


AMS1
Doc1
James
Berry



Either this can be transformed in excel itself and them imported into SAS dataset or
imported into SAS first and then transformed.
Please help!

What did you try?  How was it not what you wanted?

Just import the spreadsheet normally and then add a second data step to pull out the values from the FIRSTNAME variable and remember them.
So assuming you imported that XSLX file to create a SAS dataset named HAVE you could run this data step to create what you want.
  data want;
    length order $10 document $30 ;
    retain order document;
    set have;
    if lowcase(firstname)=:'order#:' then do;
       order=left(scan(firstname,2,':'));
       delete;
    end;
    if lowcase(firstname)=:'document#:' then do;
       document=left(scan(firstname,2,':'));
       delete;
    end;
  run;

